# Wrong output after after searching binary search tree

Tags: c++, list, tree

I'm using a binary search tree that collects strings and then orders them in post order. I also use a list that shows the line number where the string appears. I can make the BST work properly however my output in the end comes up wrong. I think the problem is occurring when I run into a word that is a duplicate. When I add a line number to the duplicate word my output screws up.

My output should look like this

```
hawaii    3

hello     1

is        3

paradise  2

to        2

welcome   2

wonderful 1 3

world    1
```

However I get this as output

```
Contents of tree:

hello 1

Contents of tree:

hello 1
wonderful 1
.
.
.

Contents of tree:

hawaii 3
hello 1
is 3
paradise 2
to 2
welcome 2
wonderful 1
world 1

Contents of tree:

is 3
paradise 2
to 2
welcome 2
wonderful 1 3
world 1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Here is the main logic

```
struct TreeNode
{
    string data;
    list<int> lineNum;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;


    TreeNode(string str,list<int> num)
    {
        data = str;
        lineNum = num;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }
};

void insert(TreeNode *&root, string newNode,list<int> num)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root = new TreeNode(newNode,num);
    }
    else if(newNode < root -> data)
    {
        insert(root -> left, newNode,num);
    }
    else
    {
        insert(root -> right, newNode,num);
    }
}

bool treeContains( TreeNode *root, string item )
{

    if ( root == NULL )
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if ( item == root->data)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ( item < root->data )
    {
        return treeContains( root->left, item );
    }
    else
    {
        return treeContains( root->right, item );
    }
}

void treeInsert(TreeNode *&root, string newItem,int num)
{
    list<int> temp;
    temp.push_back(num);
    if ( root == NULL ) 
    {
        root = new TreeNode(newItem,temp );
        return;
    }
    else if ( newItem < root->data ) 
    {
        treeInsert( root->left, newItem,num );
    }
    else 
    {
        treeInsert( root->right, newItem,num );
    }
}

void printTree(TreeNode *node)
{
    list<int>::iterator i;

    if ( node != NULL )
    {
        printTree(node->left);
        cout <<node->data;
        for( i = node->lineNum.begin(); i != node ->lineNum.end(); ++i)
            cout<<" "<<*i;

        cout << endl;

        printTree(node->right);
    }
}

TreeNode search(TreeNode *root, string item)
{
    while ( root != NULL )
    {
        if(item == root->data)
        {
            break;
        }

        if ( item > root->data )
        {
            root = root-> right;
        }
        else if(item < root->data )
        {
            root = root-> left;
        }

        if(root == NULL)
        {
            cout << "error";
        }

    }
    return *root;
}

int main()
{
    TreeNode *root;
    root = NULL;
    ifstream test("test.txt");
    istringstream strLine;
    string line, word;
    list<int> lineNum;

    int currentLine=0;

    // Go line by line
    while (getline(test,line))
    {
        ++currentLine;

        strLine.clear();
        strLine.str(line);

        lineNum.push_back(currentLine);
        // Now from the line read word by word
        while (strLine >> word)
        {

            // if word is already in tree search tree for node and line number
            if (treeContains(root,word))
            {
                *root = search(root,word);
                root->lineNum.push_back(currentLine);
                cout << "\nContents of tree:\n\n";
                printTree(root);

            }
            // if word is new add to tree insert node
            else
            {
                treeInsert(root,word,currentLine);  
                cout << "\nContents of tree:\n\n";
                printTree(root);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The input text looks like this:

```
hello wonderful world
welcome to paradise
hawaii is wonderful
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: This sounds like a perfect opportunity to learn to use a debugger. It's a useful skill that'll save you a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: The problem is not stated too clearly, but I assume you're referring to the fact that "hawaii" and "hello" are missing from the last output. If so, that's probably a problem with the tree implementation - and that's code you haven't show.

Comment: I updated the code to show the BST functions

Comment: FWIW, that is a boatload of copying of `list<int>` objects. You may want to consider that last parameter should be a `const list<int>&` fo the insertion code. Also, *must* you do this with a hand-rolled tree? or is a `std::map<>` allowable?

Comment: @WhozCraig I can't use std::map<>

Comment: @FireStorm thats a darn shame, because an `std::map<std::string, std::set<int>>` would make this near-trivial. Anyway, I'll look over the tree code and see if anything pops out.

Comment: @WhozCraig After looking up information online about the map container I can see how things can be simplified. Anyways, I appreciate your help.

Comment: @FireStorm One more thing, any chance you can update your posted question to include the original input text? Thanks in advance. It may be helpful.

Comment: @WhozCraig I updated the input text on the bottom of the main code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through your code and simplified it. I'm pasting the result.
The bug disappeared :)

Your problem was mostly that you were doing the same thing twice - you were finding a node in the tree both in the "search" and in the "insert" function. The two implementations had subtle differences which lead to your bug.

I also took the liberty to move your function calls to method calls.

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct TreeNode {
        string data;
        list<int> lineNum;
        TreeNode *left;
        TreeNode *right;

    public:
        TreeNode(string str, int num) {
            data = str;
            lineNum.push_back(num);
            left = NULL;
            right = NULL;
        }


        void print() const {
            if (this->left != NULL) {
                this->left->print();
            }

            this->printNode();

            if (this->right != NULL) {
                this->right->print();
            }
        }

        static void insert(TreeNode *&root, string newNode, int num) {
            if (root == NULL) {
                root = new TreeNode(newNode, num);
            } else if (newNode < root->data) {
                TreeNode::insert(root->left, newNode, num);
            } else if (newNode > root->data) {
                TreeNode::insert(root->right, newNode, num);
            } else {
                root->lineNum.push_back(num);
            }
        }

    private:
        void printNode() const {
            list<int>::const_iterator i;
            cout<<this->data;

            for (i = this->lineNum.begin(); i != this->lineNum.end(); ++i) {
                cout<<" "<<*i;
            }

            cout << endl;
        }
};


int main()
{
    TreeNode *root;
    root = NULL;
    ifstream test("test.txt");
    istringstream strLine;
    string line, word;
    int currentLine=0;

    // Go line by line
    while (getline(test,line)) {
        ++currentLine;
        strLine.clear();
        strLine.str(line);

        // Now from the line read word by word
        while (strLine >> word) {
            TreeNode::insert(root,word,currentLine);
        }
    }

    cout << "\nContents of tree:\n\n";
    root->print();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking over everything I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I stared awhile. Even wrote my own version of this, but in the end this is what I think you should do:

First, change `treeInsert()` to look like this:

```
void treeInsert(TreeNode *&root, const string& newItem,int num)
{
    if (root == NULL )
    {
        root = new TreeNode(newItem, list<int>(1, num));
        return;
    }

    if (newItem < root->data )
    {
        treeInsert( root->left, newItem, num );
    }
    else if (root->data < newItem)
    {
        treeInsert( root->right, newItem, num );
    }

    else
    {   // found the item. just add it to the node's list
        //  if it isn't already there.
        if (find(root->lineNum.begin(), root->lineNum.end(), num) == root->lineNum.end())
            root->lineNum.push_back(num);
    }
}
```

**Why?**: This effectively first checks to see if the node is NULL. If it is, then we have to make a new node, and do so, which a new list of one item: the current line number. If the root is *not* NULL, then we have three options.

1. If the word is "less" than the root word, move down the left tree.
2. Else if the word is "greater" than the root word, move down the right tree
3. Else it is **neither** less nor greater, therefore it **must** be equal, so search the line list for the current line number, and if it isn't present, add it.

This alone solves *many* problems. For one it reduces the other change I would make which is to your *main* function (and it gets *much* simpler):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TreeNode *root = NULL;

    ifstream test("test.txt");
    string line;
    int currentLine=0;

    // Go line by line
    while (getline(test,line))
    {
        ++currentLine;

        istringstream strLine(line);
        string word;
        while (strLine >> word)
        {
            treeInsert(root, word, currentLine);
            cout << "\nContents of tree:\n";
            printTree(root);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, this allows you to throw out the following functions, which are not needed:

```
void insert(TreeNode *&root, string newNode,list<int> num);
bool treeContains( TreeNode *root, string item );
TreeNode search(TreeNode *root, string item);
```

With the changes I pointed out, the following is the output I think you're expecting:

```
Contents of tree:
hello 1

Contents of tree:
hello 1
wonderful 1

Contents of tree:
hello 1
wonderful 1
world 1

Contents of tree:
hello 1
welcome 2
wonderful 1
world 1

Contents of tree:
hello 1
to 2
welcome 2
wonderful 1
world 1

Contents of tree:
hello 1
paradise 2
to 2
welcome 2
wonderful 1
world 1

Contents of tree:
hawaii 3
hello 1
paradise 2
to 2
welcome 2
wonderful 1
world 1

Contents of tree:
hawaii 3
hello 1
is 3
paradise 2
to 2
welcome 2
wonderful 1
world 1

Contents of tree:
hawaii 3
hello 1
is 3
paradise 2
to 2
welcome 2
wonderful 1 3
world 1
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I learned a lot tonight. Thank you for spending the time reviewing and explaining the code. Thanks a million.

Comment: @FireStorm No problem. this was the minimal change I could see that would let you use all your relevant existing code and end up working right. There are still many ways I would write this differently, but thats me; this is yours. Most of it wasn't too bad. I made no changes to your node structure or your printer, for example. Anyway, glad it helped.